# slow aggregate on multiple columns

Tags: kdb

This kdb query that aggregates multiple columns takes approximately 31 seconds compared to 3 seconds with J

Is there a faster way to do the sum in kdb?

Ultimately this will be running against a partitioned database on the 32-bit version

```
/test 1 - using symbols

n: 13000000;
cust: n?`8;
prod: n?`8;
v: n?100
a:([]cust:cust; prod:prod ;v:v)

/query 1 - using simple by
q)\t select sum(v) by cust, prod from a
31058

/query 2 - grouping manually
\t {sum each x[`v][group[flip (x[`cust]; x[`prod])]]}(select v, cust, prod from a)
12887

/query 3 - simpler method of accessing
\t {sum each a.v[group x]} (flip (a.cust;a.prod))
11576

/test 2 - using strings, very slow
n: 13000000;
cust: string n?`8;
prod: string n?`8;
v: n?100
a:([]cust:cust; prod:prod ;v:v)

q)\t select sum(v) by cust, prod from a
116745
```

comparison J code

```
n=:13000000
cust=: _8[\ a. {~ (65+?(8*n)#26)
prod=: _8[\ a. {~ (65+?(8*n)#26)
v=: ?.n#100

agg=: 3 : 0 
keys=:i.~ |: i.~ every (cust;prod)
c=.((~.keys) { cust)
p=.((~.keys) { prod)
s=.keys +//. v
c;p;s
)

NB. 3.57 seconds
6!:2 'r=.agg 0'
3.57139

 ({.@$) every r
13000000 13000000 13000000
```

**Update:**
From the kdbplus forums, we can get down to about 2x the speed difference

```
q)\t r:(`cust`prod xkey a inds) + select sum v by cust,prod from a til[count a] except inds:(select cust,prod from a) ? d:distinct select cust,prod from a
6809
```

**Update 2: added another dataset per @user3576050**
This dataset has the same overall number of rows, but is distributed 4 instances per group

```
n: 2500000
g: 4
v: (g*n)?100
cust: (g*n)#(n?`8)
prod: (g*n)#(n?`8)
b:([]cust:cust; prod:prod ;v:v)
q)\ts select sum v by cust, prod from b
9737 838861968
```

The previous query runs poorly on the new dataset

```
q)\ts r:(`cust`prod xkey b inds) + select sum v by cust,prod from a til[count b] except inds:(select cust,prod from b) ? d:distinct select cust,prod from b
17181 671090384
```

Comment: The query itself is as simple as it gets, but you could try applying the parted or group attribute to cust and/or prod, which will make it run much faster (at the expense of the initial time taken to actually to the attribute)

Comment: thanks, on my actual data I do have the g# attribute but it does not seem to have helped. It could be that the g# attribute doesn't work as effectively across partitions?

Comment: That's strange both `p` and `g` attributes should make some impact. The only other thing I can think of is breaking the table into smaller subsets, akin to http://code.kx.com/wiki/Cookbook/alternateInMemLayouts

Comment: I find it hard to believe that kdb would be almost 10 times slower in a fair comparison, but I don't know J so can't inspect your J code. Are you sure you're not somehow pre-calculating something in the J code?

Comment: @terrylynch - nothing is being precalculated in the J code.

Answer (score 2):

If you update this data less frequently than you query it, how about pre-computing a group index? It’s about the same cost to create as a single query, and it allows querying at ~30x the speed.

```
q)\ts select sum v by cust,prod from b
14014 838861360
q)\ts update g:`g#{(key group x)?x}flip(cust;prod)from`b
14934 1058198384
q)\ts select first cust,first prod,sum v by g from b
473 201327488
q)
```

The results match up to row order and schema details:

```
q)(select sum v by cust,prod from b)~`cust`prod xasc 2!delete g from select first cust,first prod,sum v by g from b
1b
q)
```

(BTW, I know essentially nothing about J, but my guess would be that it’s computing a similar multi-column group index. q’s `g` index is unfortunately (currently?) limited to plain vector data—if it were possible to somehow apply it to the *combination* of `cust` and `prod`, I expect we’d see results like mine from the simple query.)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a pathological dataset, a set of random symbols of length 8 will have few duplicates making the grouping redundant.

```
q)n:13000000; (count distinct n?`8)%n
0.9984848
```

p#/g# attributes(mentioned in comments above) will have no impact on performance for the same reasons.

You will see better performance with more appropriate data.

```
q)n:1000000
q)
q)a:([]cust:n?`8; prod:n?`8; v:n?100)
q)b:([]cust:n?`3; prod:n?`3; v:n?100)
q)
q)\ts select sum v by cust, prod from a
3779 92275568
q)
q)\ts select sum v by cust, prod from b
762 58786352
```

Comment: Thanks, I added a more representative example above, which still runs slower than J